# How can I collect data from Yahoo calendar and webmail calendar for include sync them in a flutter calendar application?

Tags: flutter

I'm creating a mobile calendar in Flutter and I would like sync it with a Yahoo Calendar and a webmail calendar. How can I do that ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to access their API. Which is like a backdoor for apps to get specific data. The API should be on the official site of the service.

Comment: yes but i don't get and Api can help me  for yahoo calendar and for webmail calendar